_mui_material_useScrollTrigger__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function
i'm building a project with NextJS and MUI and facing this error importing useScrollTrigger function from the MUI library.
Here's my package.json:
{
  "name": "shadypalms",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.18",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.378.0",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

My Navbar.tsx
import React from 'react';
// import {AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, CssBaseline, useScrollTrigger, Box, Container, Slide} from '@mui/material'
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import useScrollTrigger from '@mui/material/useScrollTrigger';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

function HideOnScroll(props: Props) {
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger();
  return (
    <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
      {props.children}
    </Slide>
  );
}

const Navbar = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <HideOnScroll {...props}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" color={'white'}>
            Scroll to hide App bar
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </HideOnScroll>
  )
}

export default Navbar

@mui/material/useScrollTrigger/index.d.ts
export { default } from './useScrollTrigger';

useScrollTrigger
export interface UseScrollTriggerOptions {
disableHysteresis?: boolean;
target?: Node | Window;
threshold?: number;
}

export default function useScrollTrigger(options?: UseScrollTriggerOptions): boolean;

Full Error:
components/Navbar.tsx (20:37) @ useScrollTrigger

⨯ TypeError: (0 , _mui_material_useScrollTrigger__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function
at HideOnScroll (./components/Navbar.tsx:26:95)
at stringify (<anonymous>)
at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "3745371282"

I tried looking into Webpack issues and tried changing the imports and exports from the MUI library itself but it didn't seem to work.
